# Handling OnSelectedIndexChanged before SelectionChangeCommitted?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I'm working on an async binding control that inherits a ComboBox (and a Textbox in other scenarios, but that's not really relevant..). I've replaced a bunch of existing ComboBoxes on the forms in this application, which for most of these controls has worked perfectly. Except for one...

My box overrides the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method with the following code:

```
protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Helper.ItemsApplied)
    return; //don't worry! the index will be selected when the items are applied!

  _selectedValue = Helper.GetValue(Text);
  base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
}
```

This works fine, until someone tries to handle the value change using the [SelectionChangeCommitted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx) event. Perfectly within reason though; I shouldn't be changing their code to use the `SelectedIndexChanged`, because this functionality shouldn't execute when the value is programmatically invoked (see the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx)).

However, my functionality ***does*** need to be executed when the index is programmatically changed, but it needs to execute ***before*** the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event does! The `SelectionChangeCommitted` event is fired before the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Any ideas on how I could get round this? Preferably only by changing the code in my control and not in their form?

Comment: Can you put the code addressing the `Helper` in a method that you call in both events (before the `base` call) and use a parameter in `Helper.GetValue` that tells which event you came from?

Comment: That won't help. The problem is, I either need to have the SelectValue property when the SelectionChangeCommitted event is called AND I need to have the SelectedValue change when the selectedIndex is programatically changed.